# AMDP Select Query is fetching wrong records

Tags: amdp

I am getting wrong results when I execute the following Select Query in AMDP Procedure. The partner repeats twice with one address number which is not at all related to the value passed in the WHERE condition.

```
SELECT score( ) AS score,
                   partner,
                   rltyp,
                   addrnumber,
                   name,
                   postalcode,
                   street,
                   street4,
                   country
    FROM zcdsbpaddr
    WHERE
      CONTAINS ( zcdsbpaddr.name, :im_name1, FUZZY(0.8, 'similarCalculationMode=compare, textSearch=compare, bestMatchingTokenWeight=0.3' ) ) AND
      CONTAINS ( zcdsbpaddr.postalcode, :im_post_code1, FUZZY(0.8) ) AND
      CONTAINS ( ( zcdsbpaddr.street, zcdsbpaddr.street4 ), :im_street, FUZZY(0.7) ) AND
      ( :im_country = '' OR zcdsbpaddr.country = :im_country )
      ORDER BY score( ) DESC;
```

It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Please provide some minimal data (with values) to reproduce, provide what values you get and what values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is caused by your CDS view `zcdsbpaddr`, not by the SELECT or AMDP that you describe.

Check the data preview of that view - F8 in the ABAP Development Tools - to verify that it produces the records you expect.

What you describe sounds like a misled JOIN in that view. For more insights, kindly also provide that view's code or a diagram that describes its graphical composition.

FUZZY or not, your SELECT query does nothing but choose a small portion of the records that that view provides. I see no way how it could be responsible for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by making below changes:

1. CDS Client Dependent adding `@ClientHandling.type: #CLIENT_DEPENDENT` annotation.
2. Modified the AMDP method signature by adding `AMDP OPTIONS READ-ONLY CDS SESSION CLIENT current`.
3. Passed `SESSION_CONTEXT('CLIENT')` in the query WHERE condition